# Random object in Unity

Tags: object, unity-game-engine, collider

I want to make an endless runner game.  I have 2 objects, one on the top and one on the bottom. Players have to jump between or squat on the objects. I made a script which creates those objects, but sometimes two object are created on the same position, so the Players can't do anything. How to solve that? Can I check other objects on the axis X, but not by a collider?

Comment: why not use a collider?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep track of these objects, and whenever you create a new one, look at the ones you have already created to make sure that the `X` position is not the same as any of them.

Comment: I cant use collider because i have one and this check collision to player

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are asking us to give you our level generator and game controller source code! You have to write one for your game. Not because we don't want to give you the code but because each game must have its own.

For starters you can:

- split your game area to a matrix then have an array of some sort, where each cell can have a game object or be empty. game objects then can have their own local position within that cell. obviously one cell can't contain two game objects.
- have a level generator which tells the game controller where should spawn new objects. However you should implement something in the level generator to prevent overlaps.

look at this psudo code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (player.transform.position.x + Half_of_screen_width_plus_margin > nextX)
    {
        Spawn(tmp[i].prefab, nextX);
        nextX += tmp[i].distanceToNext;
        i++;
    }

}
```

`Half_of_screen_width_plus_margin` is for the game to foresee what's coming

`tmp[]` is a collection of (not-instantiated) objects to be instantiated. each object is defined arbitrarily.

As you see the script checks for the next position every fixedDeltaTime seconds, and compares the position x of the end of the screen with the next position x. If passed then creates the next object and change the next position x to a further location.

If you want to use random generation then tmp[] should be change to tmp. where with each instantiation the next is generated:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (player.transform.position.x + Half_of_screen_width_plus_margin > nextX)
    {
        Spawn(tmp.prefab, nextX);
        nextX += tmp.distanceToNext;

        tmp = generate_new_random_object();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the function to instantiate your gameobject, check if the x position of the last gameobject isn't the same as the one you gonna use.

```
    private Vector3 LastObjectPosition, NewObjectPosition;
    private float minDistanceBetweenTwoObstacles = 5;

    public void InstantiateNewObstacle()
    {
        // Check if the x position of the new object isn't the same 
        // as the the x position of the last object
        if (NewObjectPosition.x != LastObjectPosition.x)
        {
            // Instantiate your gameobject
            MyInstantiate();
        }
        // Else increase the x value for the x position of the new object 
        // and then instantiate your gameobject
        else
        {
            NewObjectPosition.x += minDistanceBetweenTwoObstacles;
            MyInstantiate();
        }
    }

    public void MyInstantiate()
    {
        // Instantiate your prefab at the NewObjectPosition position
        Instantiate(new GameObject(), NewObjectPosition, new Quaternion());
        // Save the position of the new object as the position 
        // of the last object instantiated 
        LastObjectPosition = NewObjectPosition;
    }
```

Hope this can help you !

Comment: New object will never have the same position.x because this all time move